# Linux character device driver: How to handle signals?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm attempting to create a small char device driver which creates a file as `/dev/foobar`. Among the file operations callbacks, I have

```
ssize_t read(file* filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos) 
{ 
   printk(KERN_INFO "device_read(%p,%s,%d)", filp, buf, count);
   return 0;

}

ssize_t write(file* filp, char* buf, size_t count, loff_t* f_pos) 
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "device_write(%p,%s,%d)", filp, buf, count);
   return 0;
}
```

But when I try reading from the file with `cat /dev/foobar`, it fills the message buffer completely and the system grinds to a halt and I must delete `/var/log/` or some of its contents since my virtual drive is full.

I cannot abort the reading with `Ctrl-C` or something. How can I make the process abortable?

Comment: Returning 0 from `read` function means EOF, so the function shouldn't be called repeatedly by `cat` command. But returning 0 from `write` just tell VFS to rerun this function. Are you sure  that problem is caused by *reading* from the file, not by *writting* into it (e.g. with output redirection `> /dev/foobar`)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, you are right.

Comment: I am not sure if it is connected with problem, but printing buffer with %s is general a bad idea. It excepts null terminated string, what in general is not a true with buffers.

Comment: @MarcinKajzler I see; I copy-pasted this from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf, I basically know nothing about kernel programming.